# vscode: debugging single unittest method

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

Python: 3.8.5
vscode: 1.61.2
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 on VM

When trying to run an individual unittest in debug mode, inserted breakpoints do not show any effect, i.e. stop the debugger at the specified location.

### Actual behaviour

When right-clicking on the green debug triangle on the left of a unittest method and selecting "Debug Test", the code seems to be run, but
a) it does not stop at any given and activated breakpoint
b) it does not show any output in Python Test Log or in the active terminal.

"seems to run" means, the status bar at the bottom turns orange and shows "running tests..." and the mentioned green triangle turns into a turning circle for a couple of seconds.

### Expected behaviour

a) The debugger stops at the breakpoint
b) Test output like assertions, prints etc are shown in the Test Log

### Steps to reproduce:

- Create a unittest module with a couple of simple test functions.
- Add a breakpoint
- Right-click > Debug Test on the respective test method

Comment: If anybody can reproduce the problem, please comment, even if you have no solution.

Comment: With the example code in [Python Testing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_example-test-walkthroughs), i can debug it successfully and it stops at breakpoint. Can you have a try?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did use the given code and got the same result: code seems to be run and then the test stops without any sign of result (Test Log empty).

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with extension or VS Code, please [reset VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code) and see if it helps.

Comment: Got no luck... I reset vscode and installed only the python extension. Problem still there... I even removed vscode itself, removed the user data folders and reinstalled. Still the same. Surprisingly on another vm it works.?!?!?!

Comment: I can reproduce this

Answer (score 0):

You may have confused the `breakpoint()` function with the line breakpoint feature (adding a red dot  to the line number). The function does not trigger the debugger, but the feature does. To use the feature, you need to click on the left margin of the code editor and create a red dot next to the line number. Then, run the "debug-test" command and the debugger will open in VS code. This is how you can set a breakpoint in your code.